# How to display user input from text field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a form with a username, password and verification pin inputs. The user enters their username and password and clicks sign in, which will unhide a div that allows them to enter their verification pin. In the hidden div it shows up 'Hello this account is using a verification pin' however I would like to know if there is a way where I can make it say 'hello //username that was entered// this account is using a verification pin'. How would I achieve this?

The button that unhides the div

```
<input class="btn_green_white_innerfade btn_medium" type="button" 
name="submit" id="userLogin" value="Sign in" width="104" height="25" 
border="0" tabindex="5" onclick="showDiv()">
```

The field where the user enters the username.

```
<label for="userAccountName">username</label><br>
<input class="textField" type="text" name="username" 
id="steamAccountName" maxlength="64" tabindex="1" value=""><br>&nbsp;<br>
```

The message that shows up in the hidden div

```
<div class="auth_modal_h1">Hello <span 
id="login_twofactorauth_message_entercode_accountname"></span>!</div>
<p>This account is currently using a verification pin.</p>
        </div>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var username = document.getElementById("steamAccountName").value
document.getElementById("login_twofactorauth_message_entercode_accountname").innerText = username
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the dumb question but where do I place this code?

Comment: In the same function block as where you unhide the verification pin div.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. You can use the DOM. In your `showDiv() function` you could fetch the entered username with the dom. You could do something like:

```
function showDiv() {
    const username = document.getElementById("userLogin");
    const div = getElementById("login_twofactorauth_message_entercode_accountname")
    div.getElementsByTagName("p").innerText = "Hy " + username + ", welcome...";
}
```

This code should do the trick!

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

This basically means that everything you add to the div is done with jQuery instead of having it mixed which can lead to confusion later.

1. Add `id="username"` to your input.
2. Add `id="modaldiv"` to your hello div
3. Remove everything in that div.

   ```
   var username = $("#username").val();
   var divhtml = "Hello " + username + " <span 
     id='login_twofactorauth_message_entercode_accountname'></span>!
   $("#modaldiv").html(divhtml);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will definitely get you started. It allows you to get the value that the user has entered in the input box with [`.value`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp) and add content to another div with [`.innerHTML`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp).

```js
var displayUsername = function() {

  var username = document.getElementById('username').value
  
  if(username != '') {
  
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Hello '+username+'!'
  
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">

<button class="clickMe" onclick="displayUsername()">Click ME!</button>

<div id="message"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added an id="feedback" to your html:

```
<div id="feedback" class="auth_modal_h1" style="display:none;">
    Hello <span id="login_twofactorauth_message_entercode_accountname"></span>!
    <p>This account is currently using a verification pin.</p>
</div>
```

then, I added this javascript:

```
<script>
    function showDiv() {
        document.getElementById("login_twofactorauth_message_entercode_accountname").innerHTML = document.getElementById("steamAccountName").value;
        document.getElementById("feedback").style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```